# Tailwind animations not working in angular when switching routes

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, angular-routerlink, flowbite

Im Using a plugin named flowbite and i have used a component from it. When I navigate to a different route, the animations in the navbar are not working. When i use href instead of routerLink, the animations are working as the page gets refreshed. Please suggest a solution for this.

I tried using ngafterview Init but it was not proper, so i did not get the expected result

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.